# Port 7071 is unavailable when debugging locally

Tags: azure-functions

I had previous function execution crashing and burning and it probably did not have a chance to clean up. Unfortunatley can't repro this easily - last time this happened when I started .Net 5-based function to debug in Visual Studio, but aborted starting process before it managed to start.
And all consequential attempts to start functions failed with error:

Port 7071 is unavailable. Close the process using that port, or specify another port using --port [-p].
I've checked ports in use and there is nothing: netstat -aon | findstr ":7071" - just returns nothing. There are no processes open that takes that port.

I've tried starting functions with the other port:

func start --dotnet-isolated-debug --port 7072
And got the same error: Port 7072 is unavailable. Close the process using that port, or specify another port using --port [-p]. And surely there are no processes that use that port.

The only way to get this resolved is a PC reboot, but I'm not a fan of this.